# Right to Left Horizontal Timeline isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, right-to-left

I've created a jQuery plugin to create a Horizontal Timeline. Now I'm trying to add a Right to Left (RTL) option. I've managed to swap round most of the functions so it's going right to left, but I'm struggling to get the scrolling of the timeline to work as intended. I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/studocwho/jmbspr31/8/)

The piece of code I'm stuck on is this:

```
Timeline.prototype._updateTimelinePosition = function (event, timelineComponents) {
    if (this.settings.useRTL == false) {
            // Get the css left value of the targeted event date
        var eventLeft = Number(event.css('left').replace('px', '')),
            // Get the width value of the .events-wrapper
            timelineWidth = timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].width(),
            // Get the width value of the events (previously set)
            timelineTotalWidth = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].width();

        this._translateTimeline(timelineComponents, - eventLeft + timelineWidth/2, timelineWidth - timelineTotalWidth); 
    }
    else {
        /* RTL */

            // Get the css left value of the targeted event date
        var eventRight = Number(event.css('right').replace('px', '')),
            // Get the width value of the .events-wrapper
            timelineWidth = timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].width(),
            // Get the width value of the events (previously set)
            timelineTotalWidth = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].width();

        // This line here...
        this._translateTimeline(timelineComponents, - eventRight + timelineWidth/2, timelineWidth - timelineTotalWidth);    

    }    
}

Timeline.prototype._translateTimeline = function (timelineComponents, value, totalTranslateValue) {
    // Only negative translate value
    if (this.settings.useRTL == false) var value = (value > 0) ? 0 : value;

    /* RTL*/
    // This line here...
    else var value = (value > 0) ? 0 : value;

    // Do not translate more than timeline width
    if (this.settings.useRTL == false) 
        value = (!(typeof totalTranslateValue === 'undefined') &&  value < totalTranslateValue ) ? totalTranslateValue : value;

    /* RTL */
    // This line here...
    else value = (!(typeof totalTranslateValue === 'undefined') && value < totalTranslateValue ) ? totalTranslateValue : value;


    this._setTransformValue(timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'], 'translateX', value+'px');

    // Disable the buttons if necessary
    this._buttonDisable(timelineComponents, value, totalTranslateValue);    
}
```

Where I've commented "This line here" on the RTL part is the lines I'm stuck with. I've tried so many variations of code: swapping round all the variables, swapping round all the operands and nothing seems to work correctly.

Basically what I am wanting is the Left to right functionality flipped round for right to left, both of which can be found in the jsfiddle.

The line: `this._translateTimeline(timelineComponents, - eventRight + timelineWidth/2, timelineWidth - timelineTotalWidth);` in `_updateTimelinePosition` function, is the function call to translate/move the timeline, calculating the translate value as the second argument. The timeline uses the `transform: translate()` css to translate/move the timeline along. I can't get it to get calculate properly for right to left.

**Expectation:**

- In the RTL timeline, when clicking prev/next and event buttons the timeline
  should automatically scroll along to the correct selected event.
- The timeline should start from the right, but sometimes calculates
  this wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the issue here, but moving LTR and RTL produces the exact same results ( I don't see a "This line here" on your RTL timeline )

Comment: @Keith, No they don't produce the same results when you click the events or prev/next buttons. The "this line here", is a comment in the code in this question. But I shall update the jsfiddle javascript to include this too.

Comment: You do not have to flip around anything from RTL and LTR. You can just use the RTL event but on the opposite direction also. Thus, once it gets to the end or far right, change the timeline to 0.00 or loop through it in a decreasing order like 25:00 to 24:00 to 23:00  ... etc to 0:00.

Comment: @Juniar, I am very new to RTL stuff... what is the RTL event? Also I'm not sure I understand your what you mean. I have already changed the dates in to descending order, I'm just wanting to figure out how to translate the timeline from right to left, making sure that the selected event is always in view. Possibly show me what you mean in jsfiddle. Is there any formal documentation about RTL?

Comment: @Juniar Unless you mean instead of trying to do the whole timeline right to left, just change the order of the events?

Comment: @Studocwho, yes Right to Left. You will need a Loop to loop through both direction, in an increasing order then decreasing order or in reverse.